# File sharing among pc and iMac

Tags: windows, macos, networking, performance, network-shares

iMac and pc are connected with gigabit router to share files. What suggestions you might have to speed up the sharing of files from one computer to the other

Comment: What protocol are you using for file sharing? What kind of performance are you getting right now, in MB/sec?

Answer (score 1):

The protocol used by Windows file sharing (SMB) is very inefficient compared to some other options.  I like NFS on Unix/Linux systems but have never used it on Mac or PC.  You could also try SCP or FTP to transfer individual files.